# How to get value of array based on matching on key

Tags: php, arrays

Hi i am working on some operations where i need to get value of array from its key.

I have `$attr_color` variable with the value `red`.

So if `red` is in the array then it needs to be return its value.

**Below is my array :**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [label] =>  
            [value] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [label] => red
            [value] => 32
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [label] => green
            [value] => 33
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [label] => pink
            [value] => 34
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [label] => black
            [value] => 35
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [label] => white
            [value] => 36
        )

)
```

I have tried below code but  it returns blank :

```
$attr_color = "red";

//$response is my array which i have mention above.
if(in_array($attr_color,array_column($response,"label")))
{

    $value = $response['value'];
    echo "Value".$value;
    exit;
}
```

Help ? where i made mistake ?

Comment: You cannot acces $response['value'] directly. That's what you are doing wrong

Comment: You have to get the index of the array with `label=red`, then use `$response[$index]['value']`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [array_search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php), ***and check for false***:

```
$index = array_search($attr_color, array_column($response,"label"));
if ($index !== false) {
    echo $response[$index]['value'];
}
```

Comment: Practical implemented this and this is actually feasible solution for me thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try this simple solution, hope this will help you out. Here we are using `array_column` for getting columns and indexing it with `keys` and `values`, Where `keys` are `labels` and `values` as `value`

[**Try this code snippet**](https://eval.in/781555) (with sample inputs)

```
$result=array_column($array, 'value',"label");
$result=array_filter($result);
echo $result["red"];
```

Answer (score 2):

In your case it's enough to use a regular `foreach` loop:

```
$attr_color = "red";
$value = "";

foreach ($response as $item) {
    if ($item['label'] == $attr_color) {
        $value = $item['value'];
        break;   // avoids redundant iterations
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By using   `array_column` with third parameter and `array_search` as

```
 $attr_color="red";
 $arr = array_filter(array_column($response, "label", 'value'));// pass thired parameter to make its key
    if (array_search($attr_color, $arr)) {// use array search here

        echo array_search($attr_color, $arr);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try below code : using array match function :**

```
$your_value = array_search($attr_color, array_column($response,"label"));
if ($index !== false) {
    echo $response[$your_value]['value'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `array_search` instead of `in_array`

```
$attr_color = "red";

if(($index = array_search($attr_color,array_column($response,"label")))!==FALSE)
{

    $value = $response[$index]['value'];
    echo "Value".$value;
    exit;
}
```

Comment: This will not find the color when it occurs in the very first element of the array

Comment: `array_search` returns the index of the match, if there's no corresponding color in the array then it will return false. I am searching here the array of labels, not the original array. This is the shortest solution rather than using a foreach loop. But i respect all of your answers.

Comment: Did you try out what I indicated in my first comment? Did you get the output?

Comment: Okay, I get it now. It's the zero index that will return false. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$attr_color = "red";

//$response is my array which i have mention above.

$index = array_search($attr_color, array_column($response, 'label'));

if($index!==false){
    $value = $response[$index]['value'];
    echo "Value:".$value;
    exit;
}
```

Here $index will get the index of the array with label red

Comment: This will not find the color when it occurs in the very first element of the array